# Link two github repos

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, github

I want to make an opensource project . I also have private parts of the app
I thought in making 2 github repos and link them togther one is public and has the base code
and the other one is private and dependent on the first.

I also want the dependent one to update as soon as I commit a change to the open source repo and define which parts of the project to be updated automatically

Is there a better alternate to my idea ?
How could I achieve such result ?

Answer (score 1):

Repo 2 depends on Repo 1, so you should have Repo 1 setup as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in Repo 2.

I don't know if you can set behaviors to pull the changes to Repo 1 immediately, but it'd be something like:

```
cd ~/path/to/repo2
git submodule add https://url/to/repo1
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Any time Repo 1 makes changes, you can

```
git pull
```

and then update the submodules

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: I don't want all of repo 1 to be copied inside repo 2

Comment: @ShadyGheith how does Repo 2 depend on Repo 1 then? If you're going to keep code from Repo 1 in Repo 2, and that code changes, then don't those changes get tracked regardless? I'm not sure why you're saying you don't want all of Repo 1 to be copied; I'm not sure how you're imagining the source control is going to work.

Comment: If there's only a portion of Repo 1 that's useful to Repo 2 then Repo 1 might have too much stuff in one project and should be split into subprojects.

Comment: I just want to create a prototype with mock data\assets and then replace them with real data\assets. I want the prototype repo to be avalible for everyone while the other repo should be private

Comment: all the code base should be the same only the assets will be change. it's a game btw

Comment: @ShadyGheith If you're substituting mock assets for real assets then you're not linking to Repo 1 at all, are you? What are your plans if Repo 1 updates the mock assets? I don't understand how the mock assets/Repo 1 plays any part here if they're being replaced. If Repo 1 has scripts and mock assets and all you want to keep are the scripts, then this falls under my earlier comment that Repo 1 has too much content and should be split into a scripts repo that's submoduled into a public mock asset repo, to give examples, and you can also submodule the scripts repo into your private project.